# Can a subclass override a method and have different parameters?

Tags: java, c#, oop

I want to have a method in multiple subclasses which essentially get a certain thing done (like getting user info), but is declared in (and has different parameters and definitions than) the main class. Is this possible?

I know this is not really overriding, but can this be done or is it not a suitable way to structure methods?

Comment: If the new method will have different parameters then it's overloading, not overriding. A subclass can do that, there won't be any problems.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to comment?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what if overridden method replaces parameter type to its subtype?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza today I tried these scenarios using `@Override` annotation:
1) Replacing parameter type to its subclass - NOT allowed
3) Replacing return type to its subclass - allowed

Comment: @valijon my bad. You're right, using a subclass as argument is an overload not an override. You can verify those rules in JLS: [Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) and [Overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is called overloading a method. It is doable and occurs often. [Play with the fiddle here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhWhSt) Java is similar.

```
public class Parent
{        
    public virtual string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    public string GoodbyeWorld()
    {
        return "Goodbye world";
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
     // override: exact same signature, parent method must be virtual
    public override string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World from Child";
    }

     // overload: same name, different order of parameter types
    public string GoodbyeWorld(string name)
    {
        return GoodbyeWorld() + " from " + name;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var parent = new Parent();
        var child = new Child();
        Console.WriteLine(parent.HelloWorld());
        Console.WriteLine(child.HelloWorld());
        Console.WriteLine(child.GoodbyeWorld());
        Console.WriteLine(child.GoodbyeWorld("Shaun"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple versions of a method with the same name having different number of parameters. You can have all these in the main/parent class or you can add the newer versions in the subclasses only. There is no restriction on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments and the other answer, you can define a method in a subclass with the same name as a method in its superclass, but you can't override it, exactly. Both methods will still exist, so it's called *overloading*. In [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and in [C Sharp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it works pretty much the same; you just define a new method with different parameters. You *cannot* just change the return type, though. The parameters to the methods must be different in order to overload one. [Here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/method-overriding-vs-overloading/) is an article about overloading vs. overriding in Java.